# failed to clone a script to a new server

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, php-5.6

i was trying to copy this script from one of my servers to another one
both of them are ubuntu 18 with php 5.6 on them
but i keep getting internal server error without changing anything

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['importSubmit'])){
header("Location: index.php");

}
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$x = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
require('XLSXReader.php');
$xlsx = new XLSXReader($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$sheetNames = $xlsx->getSheetNames();

foreach($sheetNames as $sheetName) {
$sheet = $xlsx->getSheet($sheetName);
array2Table($sheet->getData());
function array2Table($data) {
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        echo "<td>" . escape($cell) . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

}
function escape($string) {
return htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
}
?>
```

Comment: What does the error_log tells you ? You should have more details about the error.

Comment: i cant find an error_log

Comment: (Or at least try and enable error reporting from within the script, and see if that results in it showing what is wrong.)

Comment: _“both of them […] with php 5.6 on them”_ - why oh why, even the support with security fixes ended for that version almost a year ago now. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @04FS this is not used in production so i just need this old script to work and thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are using: https://github.com/gneustaetter/XLSXReader and this library is not installed in your new server. Install it, and you should probably be good.

Comment: thanks man i found that i havent installed another library that is required by XLSXReader

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :D